# Can't access new partition via boot menu

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

I created a partition on my hard drive from about 23GB of empty space via Windows Disk Management in Windows 10. I then loaded up an Elementary OS Freya live USB and installed Elementary OS on that partition. It was partitioned as fat32 by Windows, but I reformatted it as ext4 for the eOS install. Everything seemed fine, but now I can't get to the OS I know is on that partition. Let me walk you through what I'm seeing on my end:

I boot up and hit F11 to get my boot options, I see this:

[image]

Windows Boot Manager takes me to my Windows 10 partition which works fine. The UEFI 2.0 Silicon-Power16G1100 is my USB, the live disk I used to install Elementary OS. It works fine as well.

However, when I click the first option ("UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell"), all I get is this:

[image]

Which I have no idea what that is or what to do with it.

Same problem when I select the "grub" option, I see this (I have the picture, but I guess I need more reputation? Anyway, it just says: title "GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9" then beneath that it says "Minimal BASH-like editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions" - then beneath that it has "grub>")

So I'm guessing this is a GRUB problem, but I don't really know how to go about fixing it. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I attempted to run a disk repair live usb (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/?source=typ_redirect) - I did the recommended repair and nothing changed. It gave me this URL - http://paste.ubuntu.com/13342899/

Answer (score 0):

Delete last two partitions (sda5 and sda6) - about 26 GB.

Install EOS again. Do not create partitions yourself, let EOS installer create partitions for itself during installation in last 26 GB.

Note: If you cannot start an OS after installation there is almost no chance repairing it!